# Print the lexicographically smallest permutation that satisfies the given formation

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-2.x, combinatorics

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> A DOTA game has N heroes, each with a distinct rank from [1..N]. In
>   DOTA every formation is characterized as a permutation [1...N] of
>   ranks of players.  A formation is Imba when the sum of ranks of every
>   two consecutive players is less than or equal to (N+1). Given N, you
>   are to print the lexicographically smallest permutation of ranks
>   [1...N] that makes the formation Imba.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line will contain an integer T, i.e. the number of the test
>   cases followed by T lines, each containing the value of N.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$1 \le T \le 5\$
> - \$2 \le N \le 105\$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> \$T\$ lines each containing the permutation; the numbers in each line
>   should be seperated by a single space.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 2
> 2
> 3
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 1 2
> 2 1 3
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> In the first case there are two possible permutations [1,2] and [2,1].
>   Both of the given permutations satisfy the given constraints and [1,2]
>   is lexicographically smaller than [2,1].  In the second case, the two
>   possible permutations are [2,1,3] and [3,1,2], of which the former is
>   lexicographically smaller.

Is there a more efficient way to go about doing this?

```
from itertools import permutations
def check_condition(perm,checksum):
    for i in range(len(perm)-1):
        if perm[i] + perm[i+1] <= checksum:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
testcases = int(raw_input())
current = 1
while current <= testcases:
    max_ = int(raw_input())
    checksum = max_ + 1
    list_ = range(1,max_+1)
    for perm in permutations(list_):
        #print(perm)
        if check_condition(perm,checksum):
            print(" ".join(map(str,perm)))
            break
    current += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print out the solutions for the first couple of numbers,
a pattern becomes obvious:

```
def print_first_imba(max_):
    """
    >>> print_first_imba(2)
    1 2
    >>> print_first_imba(3)
    2 1 3
    >>> print_first_imba(4)
    2 3 1 4
    >>> print_first_imba(5)
    3 2 4 1 5
    >>> print_first_imba(6)
    3 4 2 5 1 6
    >>> print_first_imba(7)
    4 3 5 2 6 1 7
    """
```

The pattern looks like:

- given an input sequence 1, 2, 3, ..., n, and an empty output list
- pop the last number from the sequence and prepend to the output
- pop the first number from the sequence and prepend to the output
- keep popping until there are no elements left in the sequence

That will be substantially faster than searching the permutation space.

The doc tests I wrote above should help a lot in implementing this alternative algorithm. Your current implementation passes these tests btw, if you reorganize your code to fit it into this method:

```
checksum = max_ + 1
list_ = range(1, max_ + 1)
for perm in permutations(list_):
    if check_condition(perm, checksum):
        print(" ".join(map(str, perm)))
        break
```

My alternative implementation also passes these tests:

```
from collections import deque

imba = deque()
highest = max_
lowest = 1
while lowest <= highest:
    imba.appendleft(highest)
    highest -= 1
    if lowest < highest:
        imba.appendleft(lowest)
        lowest += 1
print(" ".join(map(str, imba)))
```

In case you don't know, you can run doc tests with `python -m doctest yourfile.py`.

I also recommend to go a bit further and separate printing from the main logic, by renaming this method to `get_first_imba` and make it return `perm` instead of printing it.